# How do I use two languages simultaneously in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I am working on a document that involves two languages simultaneously.

In Open Office I have created a 2-column table, with the left-hand column set to English and the right-hand column set to the other language (for spell checking, grammar, hyphenation, ...).

Now I'd like to invite others to collaboratively edit this document, and a Google document almost seems like a good solution.

How do I do the same thing in Google Docs? I can only find a language setting for the entire document.

Comment: You can add a two-column table in Google Docs as well, if that works for you

Comment: @Kaspi Ok, but I still can't see how to set one language (e.g. English) for the first column and another language (e.g. German) for the second column.